# Mouseenter and mouseleave event with window scroll event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to measure the time that a mouse cursor is in a specific area (div-container). See code below.

Until now, the leave and enter times (hover-times) are only measures when the mouse cursor enters and leaves the respective container (due to the mouseleave and mouseenter event) but not when the user uses mouse wheel or scrolls the window. My goal is to change the code in a way that the hover time is also measured when the window is scrolled (e.g. the user uses the mouse wheel).

I already tried to implement a .scroll() event with the selector 'document'.

Has anyone already encountered the same problem and has a solution for the problem?

```js
var hover_events = {};
var enter_time;
var leave_time;


$(".element").on('mouseenter', function(d) {
  enter_time = Date.now();
  hover_events[d.target.id] = {
    element_id: d.target.id,
    enter_time: enter_time,
    leave_time: undefined,
  };

});

$(".element").on('mouseleave', function(d) {
  leave_time = Date.now();
  hover_events[d.target.id]["leave_time"] = leave_time;

  console.log(hover_events[d.target.id])
  delete(hover_events[d.target.id]);

});
```

```css
.element {
  margin: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

#scroll {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="scroll">
  <div class="element" id="test">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: _mouse cursor in the area when the window is scrolled_ - do you mean if the window has scrolled, then you want to measure hover-time? or do you mean measure the scroll distance of window while hovering?

Comment: I edited my question. I mean that I want to measure the hover time even if the window is scrolled.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what's not working in your code currently

Comment: mouseleave and mouseenter only work when the mouse cursor is moved. In case that you do not move your mouse, that means that your mouse cursor stays in exactly the same position, then the code does not estimate the enter or leave time. In the simple example this is not of a big concern. However, in the real project I implemented multiple areas. Therefore, if someone scrolls over the page (e.g. uses the mouse wheel) I cannot measure the hover times.

Comment: I think I understood your task. It is necessary that the mouse events be triggered when the window is scrolled, at that moment when the mouse cursor enters the lightblue box. I'm right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that question fun to work on... And spend quite a time on it.

Here is how I thought it:

- Use `mouseenter` to record a `time_enter`.
- use the `mouseleave` to calculate a `time_spent` for the element and clear `time_enter`.
- On `mousemove`, record the x/y mouse position.
- On `scroll` for all elements, get the positions (relative to the view port) compare them with the recorded mouse position to trigger a `mouseenter` or a `mouseleave` on it.

[**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/LYyRgBR?editors=0011)

```js
console.clear();

var elements = {};
let mouse_pos = {};

// Save all element position relative to the viewport
function positions() {
  $(".element").each(function () {
    let bounding_rect = this.getBoundingClientRect();
    elements[this.id] = elements[this.id] || {};

    elements[this.id].top = bounding_rect.top;
    elements[this.id].right = bounding_rect.right;
    elements[this.id].bottom = bounding_rect.bottom;
    elements[this.id].left = bounding_rect.left;
    elements[this.id].time_spent = elements[this.id].time_spent || 0;
  });
}

// Run once on load
positions();
let keys = Object.keys(elements);

$(window).on("scroll", function () {
  positions();

  // loop all elements
  keys.forEach(function (id) {
    let item = elements[id];

    if (
      mouse_pos.x > item.left &&
      mouse_pos.x < item.right &&
      mouse_pos.y > item.top &&
      mouse_pos.y < item.bottom
    ) {
      console.log("Hovering", id);
      $(`#${id}`).trigger("mouseenter");
    } else {
      $(`#${id}`).trigger("mouseleave");
    }
  });
});

$(document).on("mousemove", function (e) {
  mouse_pos.x = e.pageX;
  mouse_pos.y = e.pageY;
  //console.log(mouse_pos)
});

$(".element").on("mouseenter", function (e) {
  elements[e.target.id].time_enter = Date.now();
  //console.log(elements);
  $(`#${e.target.id}`).addClass("hovered");
});

$(".element").on("mouseleave", function (e) {
  if (elements[e.target.id].time_enter) {
    elements[e.target.id].time_spent +=
      Date.now() - elements[e.target.id].time_enter;
    delete elements[e.target.id].time_enter;
    //console.log(elements);

    $(`#${e.target.id}`)
      .text((elements[e.target.id].time_spent / 1000).toFixed(2) + " sec.")
      .removeClass("hovered");
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.element {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.hovered {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="element" id="el_1"></div>
  <div class="element" id="el_2"></div>
  <div class="element" id="el_3"></div>
  <div class="element" id="el_4"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="element" id="el_5"></div>
  <div class="element" id="el_6"></div>
  <div class="element" id="el_7"></div>
  <div class="element" id="el_8"></div>
</div>
```